# Pandas (Python) MultiIndex from Single Index pd.DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hierarchy, multi-index, reindex

I have a df which looks like:

[image]

Let the group name of the individual columns be 'Symbol', so that a list of column names
'Symbol' = ['AAPL US Equity', 'ABT US Equity', 'BDX US Equity', 'BRO US Equity']
Let 'Returns' be the floats.
Let 'Dates' be a datetime index.

Question:
I need the df to have MultiIndex of ['Ticker', 'Dates'] with the hierarchy of it being the order i.e. 'Ticker' --> 'Dates' --> 'Returns'

Something like:

[image]

It is first grouped by 'Symbol', then by 'Date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) :

```
df = df.set_index('Dates').unstack().rename_axis(['Symbol','Date']).to_frame('Close')
```

Or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = (df.melt('Dates', var_name='Symbol', value_name='Close')
        .set_index(['Symbol','Dates'])
        .sort_index())
```

Comment: Both work! The DataFrame.melt method keeps it as a DataFrame which I need later. Thank you!